# undefined method `activated?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm trying to implement Authlogic in Rails 3 and have just been having headache after headache...I'm extremely new to rails, so please forgive me for not being an expert. I followed the railscast on the subject which has been really helpful, but as soon as i submit my create new user form via the actual website I get this:

```
undefined method `activated?'

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:37:in `create'
```

Any help would be SO appreciated...had a headache with this tonight...

Code from create method:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Registration successful."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Paste the code in your `UsersController#create` method so we can see what it's trying to do.

Comment: If anyone else hits this issue - regenerate your user_session model and fill it with:

class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  def to_key
    new_record? ? nil : [ self.send(self.class.primary_key) ]
  end
end

This fixed it for me...seems to be an error surrounding that model at the very least so take it back to basics!

Comment: Jamie, please post this as an answer (you are even allowed to accept your own answer after two days). That way, this question doesn't come up as 'unanswered. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone else hits this issue - regenerate your user_session model and fill it with:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base 
  def to_key 
    new_record? ? nil : [ self.send(self.class.primary_key) ] 
  end 
end
```

This fixed it for me...seems to be an error surrounding that model at the very least so take it back to basics!

Comment: This worked for me, but I was wondering how this fixes the issue and why? Thanks in advance if you can explain your answer :)

Comment: Thanks, i had the same error on FactoryGirl.create(:user), and I was confused because I have `activated?` method in user model.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was the existence of a user_sessions table. If you created the UserSession model through a generator, you have a migration that creates that table.

Simply deleting the table (both in test and development databases) and the migration file solved the problem for me.

Cheers,

-- José